# Ajax request receives binary data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download

I have a ajax request that uploads a file and some other data, parses it, and downloads it in an xls format.  I currently have the file uploading correct with ajax, however when the success function is called, it recieves the binary data as its parameter 'data'.  I would like to take this data and create a file with it, and present it to the user as if it had been downloaded.  is this possible?  Here is my ajax request.

```
$("#fileForm").submit(function(){
    var fileData = $("#fileInputElmt").prop("files")[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("upload",fileData);
    var url = "process.action?" + $("#fileForm").serialize();
    console.log(url);
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data:data,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success"+data);
            hideProgressBar();
        },error:function(data){
            console.log("error "+data);
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this.

```
function downloadPDF() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', API_URL, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
        bb.append(this.response); // Note: not xhr.responseText

        var blob = bb.getBlob('application/pdf');
        var blobURL = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);

        window.open(blobURL);
    }
};

xhr.send(createRequest());
}
```

only works in newer browsers , Chrome IE9+ etc...

The example users the xhr but if your ajax call returns binary you should be able to do something similar.